# Testar sistema Web em Smartphone

Tags: php, aplicação-web, testes

Tenho uma aplicação em `PHP` que esta rodando no `XAMPP` e esta sendo acessado via `http://localhost/` ela esta funcionando no computador porém gostaria de testa-la em meu `smartphone` (via `browser`), como faço para testa-la no meu smartphone?

Detalhes:

- Ambos `PC` e `smartphone` estamos na mesma rede wi-fi.
- `Smartphone` é da 4ª geração.
- Sistema operacional do `Smartphone`: Android 4.4
- Sistema operacional do `PC`: Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa acessar do smartphone pelo endereço de IP do seu computador na rede local.

Para descobrir o endereço de IP do seu computador, abra o menu Iniciar e navegue pelo menu `Todos os programas > Acessórios > Prompt de Comando`. Abra o Propmpt de Comando e digite `ipconfig` e tecle Enter. Este comando irá resultar nas suas configurações de endereço de IP. Agora, no resultado exibido no Prompt de Comando procure pela linha que contém `Endereço IPv4` o valor logo na sequência é o seu endereço de IP.

Exemplo:

```
C:\Users\william.urbano>ipconfig

Configuração de IP do Windows


Adaptador Ethernet Conexão local 2:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . : 
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::35a7:b255:2504:d0e9%14
   Endereço IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 10.9.0.78
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.9.0.254

Adaptador de túnel Conexão Local:

   Estado da mídia. . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : mídia desconectada
   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . :
```

No exemplo acima, 10.9.0.78 é o endereço de IP da minha máquina. Se eu acessar ele pelo navegador de algum Smartphone estarei acessando meu servidor web.

Comment: não funcionou, ficou assim a URL no smartphone: 192.xx.56.3/PROJETOS/PortfolioCinza/index.html

Comment: O firewall do windows deve ter bloqueado ele, pode simplesmente desativar ele ou criar uma exceção para testes. E não precisa mascarar seu ip para postar aqui, pois esse ip é local, ninguém consegue fazer nada com ele. @RicardoHenrique